# How can I move Git lfs Storage from Artifactory to Github

Tags: git, github, artifactory, git-lfs

I want to move my Git lfs storage (one Git lfs repo in artifactory) with all its content to Github lfs as I want to migrate from Artifactory. My code repositories reside in Github as well hence I want to keep lfs storage in the same location.
I would like to know if lfs storage can be either moved or exported to any other storage provider. In this case Artifactory to Github.

Answer (score 0):

The query is confusing. Artifactory and Github functionalities are completely different.
GitHub is a centralised place or tool that is used to save your source code.(example .java, .c++ etc). It's a source code manager.
Artifactory is a place where you save your installable binaries. (example .war, .ear, .nuget package etc). It's a binary manager.
Can you elaborate a bit on your query.

Comment: When tracking lfs with github (without configuring other binary managers for lfs ) files are getting saved into https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/info/lfs. That is Git lfs. Which also don't need to have .lfsconfig. Maybe what I have mentioned as Github lfs confused you.
My requirement is to change the current lfs tracking which is using artifactory to be tracked in git lfs. So that finally I don't need to have an artifactory connection.